# Dynamically loadChildren in Angular based on service value condition

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-load-children

Is possible to `loadChildren` routes in Angular based on a service based value condition?

I have the following route to be loaded:

```
const routesFactory = (service: InjectedService) => {
  return [
    {
      path: "",
      runGuardsAndResolvers: "always",
      canActivate: [ApplicationStateGuard],
      canActivateChild: [ApplicationStateGuard],
      loadChildren: (): Promise<LayoutModuleV1 | LayoutModuleV2> =>
        service.condition == true
          ? import(/* webpackChunkName: "layout-v1" */ "@app/layout-v1").then((mod) => mod.LayoutModuleV1)
          : import(/* webpackChunkName: "layout-v2" */ "@app/layout-v2").then((mod) => mod.LayoutModuleV2),
    },
  ]
}

// later in the AppRouting I use as follow:

@NgModule({
  exports: [RouterModule],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: "reload", relativeLinkResolution: "legacy" })],
})
export class AppRouting {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<AppRouting> {
    return {
      ngModule: AppRouting,
      providers: [
        Service,
        {
          provide: ROUTES,
          useFactory: routesFactory,
          deps: [InjectedService],
          multi: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

// AppModule

imports: [AppRouting.forRoot()]
```

The problem is that I have a circular dependency with the `InjectedService`.

```
Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for Router. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
    at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.js:228:11)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11453:13)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11276:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:4770:33)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:4774:12)
    at Object.InjectedService_Factory [as factory] (injected.service.ts:71:25)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11457:35)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11276:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:4770:33)
    at ɵɵinject (core.js:4774:12)
```

It is possible to provide the condition to be used inside the Routing provider without using the Services condition directly?

Could be possible to only set dynamic loadChildren inside the ROUTES multiprovider and the rest of the routes inside the `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, …)` ?

Comment: Have you considered using a route guard for this? Say you have 2 modules v1 and v2, you can have the route guard return a UrlTree to `/v1` or `/v2` depending on you logic

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but doesn't work for me with lazy load of those routes

Comment: how does lazy loading affect route guards redirection?

Comment: Directly is frozen and not redirecting to the expected route